# iphone client/server app made with flash cs5, will i have issues?

Tags: iphone, flash-cs5

I've just created a simple iphone App in Flash CS5 that has a TextField and a submit button. When you submit it sends the TextField's value using POST to www.mysite.com/receive so I can save it in a DB.

My question is, do you think that iPhone, iTunes or their appStore will have any issues about sending POST info to a website? I just ask because I want to be sure of everything before paying the 99$USD subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter, Facebook, etc. all use POST requests to an API like this. It's fine.